# Why did a moderator delete my answer after the OP indicated it was correct?

Tags: discussion, support

A moderator just deleted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842496/november-30-0001-returned-on-timestamp/7842522#7842522) after I solved the OP's problem (he commented with "Worked straight away. Thanks. I'll accept when the time limit ends :)". Why was my answer deleted? I read the FAQ, and I don't think there was any good reason for deleting it. Could they at least add a comment indicating why it was deleted?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108143/moderator-deletion-of-equivalent-answers for a recent similar issue.

Comment: It's undeleted now (by the same mod)

Comment: @agf thanks for that reference. my answer has been undeleted now, but it seems like an area that is up for interpretation

Answer (score 8):

It *looks* like you initially posted a question/comment, and not an answer, but edited your post (five minutes or less after you posted it, and so the edit doesn't show up in the post's history) to include an actual answer. You didn't delete the questionable content (and complained when Lance Roberts did).

It's likely someone flagged your answer as "not an answer" either before your edit (which would be a correct flag) or after (in which case, the flag is arguable). I don't think the answer should have been deleted after your edit (but see Yoda's comment below - Robert may not have even been able to see the edit), but it *definitely* should have been edited to focus it.

You say you've read the FAQ - [take a closer look at the section on deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion).

Comment: Yes. Keep comments and answers separate!

Comment: This looks like the most likely explanation. Also, you can't really blame Robert Harvey here, because the answer was posted at `xx.32.xx` and was deleted at `xx.38.xx`, just 6 mins later. So it's highly likely that Robert never saw the updated version which was done in the grace period, leaving no trace. Deletion is understandable, because [so] moderators do not have all that much time to wait around for the OP to edit it.

Comment: @yoda: Good call; I didn't notice how close in time the posting and deletion were. [I'm not, myself, a fan of the 5-minute edit window.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make)

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for Robert, but the post was likely auto-flagged as low quality due to lack of capitalization at the beginning of sentences (particularly the word `i`) and other issues.  He probably deleted it based on that without seeing the comments.